# How to execute "peer node pause" command in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, peer

If I run this command `peer node pause -c mychannel` the following error occurs;

```
Error: as another peer node command is executing, wait for that command to complete its execution or terminate it before retrying: lock is already acquired on file /var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/fileLock
Usage:
  peer node pause [flags]

Flags:
  -c, --channelID string   Channel to pause.
  -h, --help               help for pause

/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer # peer node pause -h
Pauses a channel on the peer. When the command is executed, the peer must be offline. When the peer starts after a pause, it will not receive blocks for the paused channel.
```

I Understood that the peer needs to be in the offline state in order to execute this command. But how can I make the peer offline. There is no such command as `Peer node stop`. The only way I see is to use the docker command to stop the container, but that doesn't make any sense, as if I stop the container I won't be able to sh into the container.

Anyone please help me to execute the `peer node pause` command!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the command with which you are starting the container.

```
peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    labels:
      service: hyperledger-fabric
    environment:
      #Generic peer variables
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=fabric_test
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      # Peer specific variabes
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/host/var/run/docker.sock
        - ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
    networks:
      - test
```

As you are bringing up the peer container wtih **command: peer node start**  command.
According to fabric docs the `peer node start` command -  Starts a node that interacts with the network.
So the node is getting started as you bring up the container, I have not tried it but you can either replace that command with `peer node pause -c mychannel` as the node is not yet started that means the peer was in offline state. You can try this.